# Migrating from HTML landings to NextJS. How to parse html blocks?

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing, next.js, frontend

First of all, i know, it is a strange task, but i have no options now.
There is a ecommerce site with ~500 products. All 500 pages are looong landing pages with different blocks in them: swipers, sliders, gifs, videos, images, images with text, images with buttons, steps, tables etc...
Also each product has common blocks: ProductHero, ProductInfoTable, ManagerForm...
Again, i dont know, why they have decided to migrate this to Next, but i need to complete this task.
If, for example, each product has at least 5 unique blocks, it means, i need to create 500*5=2500 components in react, that is crazy.
I want to parse sections from old htmls and save seo plusses from them. I need to connect styles somehow. Maybe in  component of Next?
Or are there any ideas of how can i parse some sections from old htmls to insert them in my dynamic product routes? Or can i get it from backend somehow, how do i connect styles then?

Is there an option to insert these blocks with iframe? Will seo will be saved(parsed by robots)?

Comment: Are you trying to bodge a load of different old front end code together? What are these "old htmls"? You would never need to create 2500 components manually in react. What have you tried soo far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So i have ~500 products. Each product has a unique block (feature): 
- block with a button, that shows modal with animation on click, 
- block with animtation of pictures related to certain product, 
- another blocks with different animations.
- as i said before, there are many other sections, that are totally different from each other. 
All those pages were created "manually" by creating landing pages one by one. Now, i need to rewrite it all on NextJs for whatever reason. 
Can i get html blocks with styles as a string from backend and also get styles as link to set it in NextScript?